# Django: Admin, adding some new filters to a multiple choice field

Tags: django, django-admin, models

I am building an article site using django.
I've added many to many relation between my articles this way:

```
class Article (models.Model):
    # Tiny url
    url = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    short_description = models.TextField(max_length = 600)
    body = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    related = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Now in my admin site, I see multiple select box ( see image here http://img.skitch.com/20091017-mfs2mbhbuudk2rgquium1bu61d.png)

What I want is to use this box usable for a user who will chose articles to bind them to a current one. So for example, is there a way to add some filtering there? E.g. If I would like to filter all articles by section? And then dismiss previous results and filter the whole set by name, etc?

Thanks in advance

+++

I am trying to investigate possibility to add filter horizontal to admin. But after I added it this way:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('video', )

    js = ('/site_media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 
          )
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'section', 'is_published', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ('author', 'section', 'is_published', 'pub_date')
    filter_horizontal = ['related', ]
    search_fields = ['body', 'title', 'short_description', 'seo_keywords']
```

All articles vanished from admin :(

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the admin, but I'd love to be proved wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look for basic filtering, try [this](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) or [that](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_vertical):

If you want to customize filtering, you could actually do it. A little guide:

Subclass `forms.SelectMultiple` or directly the existing `FilteredSelectMultiple` from `django.contrib.admin.widgets` and make it do what you want.

Then subclass ModelAdmin in your admin.py and overwrite `formfield_for_manytomany` (look in `django.contrib.admin.options` for that method) and exchange the existing widget with your new one.

Comment: I am looking for some basic filtering. 

Can you explain me with example how to add the horizontal filter?
I tried to add this to the admin:
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('video', )

    js = ('/site_media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js', 
          )
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'section', 'is_published', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ('author', 'section', 'is_published', 'pub_date')
    filter_horizontal = ('section', 'is_published')

But all my article entries just disappeared... Where to add the filter?

Comment: AFAIK filter_horizontal only works with ManyToMany Fields. The arguments are just the fields you want to filter and NOT the fields you want to filter by. So in your case, it's just filter_horizontal = ('related',). As I pointed out, it's just basic filtering, for more advanced filtering you have to write the code yourself.